# First Person Camera In Blender Game Engine

Tags: python, game-engine

I am making a game in Blender with a first person camera. I used a mouselook script I found online, however when character motion is used for the camera's movement, I have the problem that when the character is looking at the ground and presses the <kbd>S</kbd> key, they move up. I am writing a script that will detect when the mouse moves up and down, and another that detects moving left to right.
Where would I start? I was looking at the documentation, and I found `bge.types.SCA_PythonMouse.position`, but that does not tell you when the mouse is moved. Is
there a function that does this?

Comment: Probably off-topic, but I think you're after mouse *events*, which Blender does appear to have.

Answer (score 2):

no need for a script to get mouse movements use the logic bricks :

[image]